# "Too Many Fields Defined" error

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Not sure why I am getting `"Too Many Fields Defined"` error even though I am only trying to create the Excel sheet with `6` columns in it. I thought the limit was `255` columns.

This is how my code looks:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new 

OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\MyFile.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes'"))
{
    conn.Open();
        var schema = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "Table" });

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    if (schema.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Any(r => r.ItemArray[2].ToString().ToLower() == "sheet1"))
        {
                    cmd .CommandText = "DROP TABLE [Sheet1]";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [Sheet1] ([C1] string, [C2] string, [C3] string, [C4] string, [C5] string, [C6] string)";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy. Just changed the file extension to `xlsx` and it works now.

```
OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\MyFile.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes'"))
```